# Paste option in CKeditor doesnt seem to work in Chrome and firefox

Tags: ckeditor, copy-paste, paste

Using the online ckeditor http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/classic.html
I see the past options (Paste, Paste as plain text and paste from word) doesn't copy from clipboard.
I gives the error '***Your browser does not allow you to paste plain text this way. Press Ctrl+Shift+V to paste***.' But it seems to work in IE(it prompts for allow access) and not in Chrome or Firefox.

Is this a bug or some configurations needs to done from browser or ckEditor. Cause I remember I used the same behavior few months back and it used to give a popup to paste you content to the editor.

Thanks,
Vijai

Answer (score 8):

Just add this code to config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
    event.editor.on("beforeCommandExec", function(event) {
        // Show the paste dialog for the paste buttons and right-click paste
        if (event.data.name == "paste") {
            event.editor._.forcePasteDialog = true;
        }
        // Don't show the paste dialog for Ctrl+Shift+V
        if (event.data.name == "pastetext" && event.data.commandData.from == "keystrokeHandler") {
            event.cancel();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: This solution was provided by Pixilation on GitHub: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/469#issuecomment-524185244

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not allow this because this is a security hole. Someone could steal your copied data so chrome and most other browsers do not allow you to do this. press ctrl shift and v to paste it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,If that's the case, the CKeditor should remove these three option right ? because it seems like they have it but it only throw error to user.

Comment: Well, it does work for IE. But they can make it only appear on IE.

Comment: Yes, if possible can you point to a place when I can get an official word or conformation from Ckeditor team so I can refer it to my team process. Or a existing bug regrading this also works fine.

Comment: And one more thing, the current CKeditor used in our project seems to not restrict us from doing this (on the same browser). So I am assuming this restriction is with the current version of ckeditor, can I get this somewhere in ckeditor release note of something. I am using CKEditor 4.6.

Comment: @Oceanvijai Hmm it shouldn't work on Chrome no matter the version of CKEditor, but you can try contacting them over at http://ckeditor.com/contact

Comment: how to paste on mobile?

Comment: @aje tap and hold the screen then paste, just as you normally would.

Comment: Security hole should be fixed another way. I can't do my **simple** work. How is this right ?

Comment: I sometimes get this dialog when pasting from Outlook to CKEditor 4 in Chrome or Edge. I still don't understand what triggers it, because on the same machine sometimes C&P works, sometimes not. And sometimes I get the dialog eveng thorugh CTRL+V!
If it really was a browser issue, I don't understand why I can paste into Word Online using the Paste button all the times whitout a glitch. No security holes there? So the "browsers do not allow you to do this" answer doesn't sound convincing.

Answer (score 1):

According to official ckeditor team : right now there is no solution for this issue.
Refer this link:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/469

[image: You may see the comment from one of the "ckeditor developer" (mlewand https://github.com/mlewand).]

I think currently the best possible solution is to just remove them using:

```
removeButtons : "Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord"
```

I suggest everyone who are facing this issue keep commenting them so they'll do something for this issue. **Or try using the lower version.**

Answer (score 1):

Use the CKEditor [Upload Image plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/uploadimage).

[DEMO](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/image2.html)

We had the same issue. Added the plugin and image upload and download API action.

Then remove the past buttons from the editor.

```
config.removeButtons = 'Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord';
```

Add the following code into CKEditor config.js

```
config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
config.uploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
```

After that, use CTRL + V to past the image from word doc.

I am using MVC5. So the configuration is

```
config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
config.uploadUrl = '/CkEditorUploadSupport/UploadImage';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/CkEditorUploadSupport/UploadImage';
```

MVC Controller Code ; (Controller Name "CkEditorUploadSupport" under project Controller folder)

```
     public JsonResult UploadImage()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
        {
            var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["upload"];
            
            var targetLocation = @"D:\CKTestFolder";

            if (!Directory.Exists(targetLocation))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetLocation);
            }
            var pattern = new Regex(@"[:!@#$%^&*()}{|\"":?><\[\]\\;'/,~]");

            var modifiedFileName = pattern.Replace(file.FileName, "");
            modifiedFileName = modifiedFileName.Replace("\"", " ");
            modifiedFileName = modifiedFileName.Replace("4Ã¢â‚¬Â", " ");

            // Some browsers send file names with full path.
            // We are only interested in the file name.
            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(targetLocation, modifiedFileName);
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(physicalPath);
            var newName = fileName;


            while (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
            {
                var newFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                                  + "_" + RandomString(3) +
                                  Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                physicalPath = Path.Combine(targetLocation, newFileName);
                newName = newFileName;
            }

            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

            var response = new
            {
                uploaded = 1,
                fileName = newName,
                url = "/CkEditorUploadSupport/OpenImage?imageName=" + newName
            };

            return Json(response);
        }

        var response2 = new
        {
            uploaded = 0,
            message = "Upload Error.."
        };

        return Json(response2);
    }

    public ActionResult OpenImage(string imageName)
    {
        var targetLocation = @"D:\CKTestFolder";

        var physicalPath = Path.Combine(targetLocation, imageName);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
        {
            var response2 = new
            {
                uploaded = 0,
                message = "File Not Found"
            };

            return Json(response2);
        }

        string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(imageName);
        return base.File(physicalPath, mimeType);
    }

    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
            .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
```